# How to ping ip dslam which is in other subnet

Tags: networking, router, ping, adsl2+

I want to ping ip dslam, which is in another subnet

The connection is like this:

MyPc-----Rj45----------Adsl2+ Modem---------Rj11-------Dslam 
192.168.1.4----192.168.1.1---172.80.1.3-------------172.80.1.2

-----------------LanSide-----------WanSide---------------------

The modem is set to Static Ip Address Encapsulation.

How can I ping ip dslam with this setup,
 or what do I need to change about the architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reach your dslam, otherwise you wouldn't have a connection to the internet. It is possible that the dslam does not respond to ICMP pings or you are pinging the wrong address.

192.168.1.4 is an unusual address for a dslam. Make sure you are trying to ping the wrong IP. You can check this by executing a traceroute to a website like Google on your PC. [tracert http://image.ohozaa.com/i/5ec/screenhunter_04dec.1122.20.jpg](http://image.ohozaa.com/i/5ec/screenhunter_04dec.1122.20.jpg)

Comment: I am not connected to internet through Dslam. I have other connection. Set up shown above is other thing. The details of the problem is given in below link. http://www.2shared.com/file/lkBkXNi8/Dslam_Problem.html